# Poner un String/TextView con valores numéricos en un array tipo Number

Tags: java, android

¿Se puede poner un String o un Textview que contiene datos tipo `0,8,7,9` en un array tipo Number? Lo quiero para que lo convierta en una estadística.

Éste es mi código:

```
public class Estadistica2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;

    Button btnBorrar;

    String guardado = "";
    TextView datos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_estadistica2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        datos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //PARA COGER DATOS Y BORRAR CON BOTON
        btnBorrar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBorrar);
        final Context context = this;
        final SharedPreferences sharprefs = getSharedPreferences("SP1", context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //CUANDO INICIA CARGA EL DATO
        SharedPreferences sharpref = getSharedPreferences("SP1", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        guardado = sharpref.getString("MiDato","0");
        datos.setText(guardado);

        // Inicializamos el objeto XYPlot búscandolo desde el layout:
        mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

        // Creamos dos arrays de prueba. En el caso real debemos reemplazar
        // estos datos por los que realmente queremos mostrar

        Number[] series1Numbers = {1,6,4};

        // Añadimos Línea Número UNO:
        XYSeries serie1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),// Array de datos
                SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, // Sólo valores verticales
                "Evolucion"); // Nombre de la primera serie

        // Modificamos los colores de la primera serie
        LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter
                (Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),Color.CYAN, new PointLabelFormatter());

        // Una vez definida la serie (datos y estilo), la añadimos al panel
        mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(serie1, series1Format);
```

Comment: Hola tutio y bienvenido/a a [spanish.se]. Puede serte útil leer [ask] y pasar por el [tour] para después [edit] tu pregunta. Así como está no contiene ni el detalle, ni la descripción necesaria para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: No se si he entendido bien tu pregunta, ¿quieres convertir un String tipo "0,1,2,3" en un array de Numbers?

Comment: Si,exactamente,eso es

Answer (score 1):

Un modo de hacerlo es mediante un `split` del string, con lo cual obtienes un array de strings, recorres el array y obtienes el valor númerico de cada elemento, y almacenas los valores en un nuevo array ya numérico. Por ejemplo:

```
String string = "1,2,3";
String[] a_string = string.split(",");
int int[];
for (int i=0;i<a_string.length;i++) {
  int[i] = Integer.parseInt(a_string[i];)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Se puede poner un String o un Textview que contiene datos tipo
>   0,8,7,9 en un array tipo Number?

Sí, una forma es:

1) Obtén el texto del `textView` o `EditText`:

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```

2) Crea un array de strings usando .split(",") :

```
   String[] numeros = text.split(",");
```

3) Cada elemento agregalo a tu array de enteros, convirtiéndolo previamente a entero:

```
int[] ints = new int[numeros.length];
for (int i=0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
}
```

---

Aquí tienes una [demo online](https://ideone.com/GGH5ra)